# Html, hyperlink , perl, reload

Tags: html, perl, hyperlink, reload

i have a small site in html, that calls certain functions in perl.
The site has 2 pages. Page A and B.

My problem is when i go from paga B to A or vice-versa, the content of the page isn't reloaded. So if i change something in page B and then go to page A, i still have the content before my changes.

How can i allways force the reload and especially the execution on the perl functions that read from files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Expires header for the page to something in the past. It's not clear from your question if the entire page is being generated from Perl. If not, how is it loading the "certain functions in perl"? SSI?

Comment: My page is not generated from perl. Is html with javascript, and for the purposes of reading files, directories, etc, i use perl functions that i call using the XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your .htaccess file should work, I think:

```
ExpiresActive On    
<FilesMatch "\.html$"> 
ExpiresDefault A0 
Header set cache-control: "no-cache, public, must-revalidate" 
</FilesMatch>
```